# Cannot connect to the EKS cluster after deploying with bitbucket and terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

when I deploy my **EKS cluster** in command line with **terraform** from my **terminal**. I have no problem
the deployment goes very well I can connect to the cluster and execute commands like `kubectl get svc` .

However when I go through my **bitbucket pipeline** the deployment goes well but if I try to connect on command line to my EKS cluster to execute commands.

```
_ kubectl get svc
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup 5078015BC6DAFAE1391368A19FC9.gr7.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com on 192.168.43.1:53: no such host
```

So i cheked DNS side on my VPC on EKS ec2 instance:

- I click on the **vpc**
- Action **Edit DNS hostnames**
- And i checked if **DNS hostnames was enabled**

It was activated .

thanks for your help and your advice

Answer (score 0):

I created my cluster manually and was facing same issue, in my case the error was coming because of private cluster. I selected Private Cluster option while creating the cluster. If you can re-create the cluster with public access or use bastion host the error would be resolved. Hope it helps, thanks
[EKS Cluster Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxNoa.png)

Comment: i going to check

Comment: i've checked and  **Public endPoint** is already selected . Did you set any  **mapRole** or **userRole** on your **aws-auth** in **kube-system** namespace ?

Comment: i found this on internet regarding my issue :   For security reasons, when you create an Amazon EKS cluster, only the IAM entity user or role, such as a federated user that creates the cluster, is granted permissions in the cluster's RBAC configuration in the control plane. User or role that created cluster has to login through kubectl to provide cluster access to additional users/roles.

Comment: however i can't find a solution to fix my issue